# How to get the range between two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Table1

```
ID Value

001 100
002 125
003 150
004 175
005 200
006 225
...
```

Expected Output

- If the user enters a value between 100 to 124, then id should display 001
- If the user enters a value between 125 to 149, then id should display 002
- If the user enters a value between 200 to 224, then id should display 005
- If the user enters a value between 225 to 249, then id should display 006

How to make a query for the above condition.

Need query help

Comment: Can the id's ever be out of order? Could something happen in the future where row 7 has a value of 75?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

First create the test table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp(ID INT, Val INT)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES(1, 100);
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES(2, 125);
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES(3, 150);
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES(4, 175);
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES(5, 200);
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES(6, 225);
```

Set up the test value

```
DECLARE @value INT
SET @value = 125
```

If ID is sequential (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc)

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM #Temp t1, #Temp t2
WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID -1
AND @value BETWEEN t1.Val AND t2.Val -1
```

If ID is not sequential (i.e. 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, etc)

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rownum, ID, Val FROM #Temp)
SELECT t1.id
FROM cte t1, cte t2
WHERE t1.rownum = t2.rownum -1
AND @value BETWEEN t1.Val AND t2.Val -1
```

Answer (score 3):

It'd be easier to write query to transformed table like ID, ValueFrom, ValueTo.

For this table:

```
SELECT MAX(ID)
FROM Table1
WHERE Value <= @value
```

Basically, if 155 is entered, IDs 1 2 and 3 are returned, then MAX ID is taken (3) which is the answer.

Comment: I agree with the SQL, assuming the values are always in order.  But, I totally disagree with the first sentence.  With an index on `value, id` on the current table, you get the best possible performance; with the same order assumption.

Answer (score 2):

Get the closest match and return first row previously sorting by value:

```
select top 1 id 
from range
where value <= @value
order by value desc
```

Or, if you need to incorporate this query into another:

```
select id
  from range
 where value = (select max(value) from range where value <= @value)
```

Comment: +1 : Gives the OP the desired result and doesn't assume the id's are always in order.

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE in SELECT statement....

Eg:

```
declare @c int;
set @c=120;
SELECT
    CASE 
    WHEN @c BETWEEN 100 AND 124 THEN '001'
    WHEN @c BETWEEN 125 AND 149 THEN '002'
    ELSE 'Other'
END
```

Comment: This answer makes no use of the database table.  Do you propose changing the code every time the values in the table change?